# Why the mailbox Size is Reducing while Migrating between Office 365 Tenants with Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft365

I am using Graph API for a project to get messages and attachments from one Office 365 account and post it to another o365 account. Everything going fine but mailbox is not same for the target mailbox. I checked email content and attachments and everything is there. I am unable to find why the target mailbox size is not same as source. Any help will highly appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http